# powershell - bulk create of subfolders in multiple parent folders

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I am trying to create a 'FolderB' subfolder in all folders 'Folder1' through to 'Folder200'. This is to occur only if 'Folder1' through to 'Folder200' contain a subfolder named 'FolderA'. FolderB is then to be created at the same level as FolderA. I can get FolderB created, but i cant get the script to skip any parent folders that dont contain a FolderA....

```
$root = "\\server\folder1"

ForEach ($dir in (Get-Item -Path "$root\*\" | ?{$_.PSIsContainer})){

If (!(Test-Path -Path "\*\FolderA")) {

New-Item -Path "$root\*\" -Name "FolderB" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

}

}
```

Comment: Have you noticed that you say `ForEach ($dir in...` but never reference `$dir` in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should work better for you. It actually uses the path to test against in the loop, and I fixed your If statement since you were checking to see If there was not a FolderA, then create FolderB:

```
$root = "\\server\folder1"

ForEach ($dir in (Get-ChildItem -Path "$root\*\" | ?{$_.PSIsContainer} | Select -Expand Name)){

 If ((Test-Path "$dir\FolderA")) {

  New-Item -Path "$dir\FolderB" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

 }

}
```